# Issues getting correct values from XML document C#

Tags: c#, xml

I am attempting to do several things with my XML document. I have to separate the creation of csv files by the version number. Version 4 has more fields than Version 3, therefore when a csv is generated by either version, it should be able to send it to the correct folder C:\Version 3 or C:\Version 4 depending on the number of fields in the orderedfields section. Currently Im able to load the document and get values but Im having issues. The code below only gives me one  number from the  node. Also It gives me the  value but throws the following exceptions even though the code runs:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in CsvParser.exe
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

How can I get each value without getting error and also determine version number based on the number of fields in  ?

```
XmlDocument dipConfig = new XmlDocument();
dipConfig.Load("DipConfig.xml");

foreach (XmlNode versions in dipConfig.DocumentElement.ChildNodes) /*Dip level*/
{
    //string nodename = versions.ChildNodes[0].Attributes["version"].InnerText;
    foreach (XmlNode versionNode in versions) /*Versions level*/
    {
        string versionNumber = String.Empty;
        versionNumber = versionNode.Attributes["number"].InnerText;
        Console.WriteLine(versionNumber); //only gets version # for first version

        if (versionNode.HasChildNodes)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode childNodes in versionNode) /*OrderedFields level*/
            {
                string locationPath = String.Empty;
                locationPath = childNodes.Attributes["path"].InnerText;

                Console.WriteLine(locationPath); //gets location path but throws exception
            }
        }
    }
}
```

XML file

```
<dip>
  <versions>
    <version number="4">
      <location path="C:\xRS\Output" />
      <numberOfFields> 26 </numberOfFields>
      <orderedfields>
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="&gt;&gt;Dummy" />-->
        <type>int</type>
        <!--<field key="MTCN" />-->
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="Type" />-->
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="Agent Name" />-->
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="Operator ID." />-->
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="Address" />-->
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="ID Type" />-->
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="ID No." />-->
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="ID Issuer" />-->
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="WU Card No." />-->
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="Sender" />-->
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="Receiver" />-->
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="Originating Country" />-->
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="Destination" />-->
        <type>currency</type>
        <!--<field key="Amount Sent" />-->
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="Currency Sent" />-->
        <type>currency</type>
        <!--<field key="Amount Received" />-->
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="Currency Received" />-->
        <type>currency</type>
        <!--<field key="Total" />-->
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="UID" />-->
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="Version" />-->
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="Breakdown" />-->
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="SuspectedFlag" />-->
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="FlagReason" />-->
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="&gt;&gt;File Name" />-->
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="&gt;&gt;Export Date Time" />-->
      </orderedfields>
    </version>
    <version number="3">
      <location path="C:\xRS\Output" />
      <numberOfFields> 23 </numberOfFields>
      <orderedfields>
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="&gt;&gt;Dummy" />-->
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="MTCN" />-->
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="Type" />-->
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="Agent Name" />-->
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="Operator ID." />-->
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="Address" />-->
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="ID Type" />-->
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="ID No." />-->
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="ID Issuer" />-->
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="WU Card No." />-->
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="Sender" />-->
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="Receiver" />-->
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="Originating Country" />-->
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="Destination" />-->
        <type>currency</type>
        <!--<field key="Amount Sent" />-->
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="Currency Sent" />-->
        <type>currency</type>
        <!--<field key="Amount Received" />-->
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="Currency Received" />-->
        <type>currency</type>
        <!--<field key="Total" />-->
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="UID" />-->
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="Version" />-->
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="Breakdown" />-->
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="SuspectedFlag" />-->
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="FlagReason" />-->
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="&gt;&gt;File Name" />-->
        <type>string</type>
        <!--<field key="&gt;&gt;Export Date Time" />-->
      </orderedfields>
    </version>
  </versions>
</dip>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is throwing an exception on `locationPath = childNodes.Attributes["path"].InnerText;` because the next child node after 'location' is 'numberOfFields'. The 'numberOfFields' node does not have an attribute named 'path', therefore null is returned as the object before `.InnerText`.

Have you consider using deserialization and classes to represent the configuration? You could use a tool like [Xml2CSharp.com](http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/), paste in an example of the XML and it will convert to C# classes. Then you could use objects to process the configuration information.

**Code to Process**

```
Dip dipConfig = null;
var xmlString = File.ReadAllText(@"DipConfig.xml");

using (var stream = new StringReader(xmlString))
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Dip));
    dipConfig = (Dip)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
}

foreach (var version in dipConfig.Versions.Version)
{
    Console.WriteLine(version.Number);

    foreach (var fieldType in version.Orderedfields.Type)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(fieldType);
    }
}
```

**Deserialization Classes**

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "location")]
public class Location
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "path")]
    public string Path { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "orderedfields")]
public class Orderedfields
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "type")]
    public List<string> Type { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "version")]
public class Version
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "location")]
    public Location Location { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "numberOfFields")]
    public string NumberOfFields { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "orderedfields")]
    public Orderedfields Orderedfields { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "number")]
    public string Number { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "versions")]
public class Versions
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "version")]
    public List<Version> Version { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "dip")]
public class Dip
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "versions")]
    public Versions Versions { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Really awesome stuff thanks a bunch!! One other thing how would I now cross-reference the number of fields in orderedFields to match the count to a specific version?

Comment: (1.) Do you already know that v.3 has 23 fields, v.4 has 26 fields, v.n = N fields, etc.? 

(2.) Are you verifying that the actual number of Orderedfields types (`version.Orderedfields.Type.Count()`) is equal to the NumberOfFields value (`version.NumberOfFields`)? 

(3.) What should happen if they don't match?

Comment: Yes your first question is correct if version.Orderedfields.Type.Count is equal to version.numberOfFields then thats how we determine the version based on the number of columns in the csv file. If it turns out that based on the match its v3 then only files of that version should be collated and the same for v4

Comment: I tried: 

foreach (var version in dipConfig.Versions.Version)
            {
                int numFields = version.Orderedfields.Type.Count();
                Console.WriteLine(numFields);
                //Console.WriteLine(version.Number);

but I got back 26 two times..

Comment: Check the XML file. There are 26 `<Type>...</Type>` items in both versions. The only different item is for the `<type>int</type>` and `<type>string</type>` for the `<!--<field key="MTCN" />-->` item.

Comment: Stringfellow is it possible to chat with you briefly about this project im working on. what youve contributed has really helped, Now I feel like I can get this done before monday's deadline for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication45
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var groups = doc.Descendants("version")
                .GroupBy(x => (int)x.Attribute("number"))
                .ToList();

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                foreach (XElement row in group)
                {
                    string location = (string)row.Element("location").Attribute("path");
                    int fields = (int)row.Element("numberOfFields");
                    string[] fieldTypes = row.Descendants("type").Select(x => (string)x).ToArray();
                    Console.WriteLine("Version : '{0}', Location : '{1}', Number Of Fields : '{2}', Columns : '{3}'", group.Key.ToString(), location, fields.ToString(), string.Join(",", fieldTypes));
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();


        }

    }
}
```